# How to separate a full name column into first name column and last name column in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, report

Say I have a column called full_name:

```
  |  full_name |
    Johnson,Matt
```

So all the names inputted into this full name column are separated by a comma and no spaces, so how would I write a simple query to create a separate first name, and separate last name column in a case like this?

Comment: Take a look at [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/), though.

Comment: Specifically for BigQuery, I have tested the following query and it runs correctly, the post you are referencing as duplicated have invalid functions for BigQuery such as RIGHT and LEFT



select   
  name,  
  SUBSTR(name,1,STRPOS(name,',')-1) as FirstName, 
  SUBSTR(name,STRPOS(name,',')+1,LENGTH(name)) as LastName  
FROM test_dataset.tabletest;